# SSIS - Passing variable as column name in where clause of an ado.net source SQL command expression

Tags: variables, ssis, ado.net

I'm trying to build a template SSIS package that will pull from our source system and populate our load tables. The package works as follows, since we're taking from Oracle and moving to SQL Server.

Variable of "SourceDelta", String, value is blank
Execute SQL Task that is a select statement against a SQL table holding the delta column name, LastUpdateDT, the result set is mapped to the variable SourceDelta.

I then have a data flow task, where the source is an ado.net source. I have an expression on the data flow task which is:

```
select *    
from VariableSourceLocation    
where    
SourceDelta >= ##    
and SourceDelta < ##
```

Fine, you'd think, it'd populate the SourceDelta colum name into the expression. However, when opening the data flow task and opening the ado.net source, the sql command text reads as follows:

```
select *    
from VariableSourceLocation (sets correctly showing the value)    
where    
BLANK>= ##    
and  BLANK< ##
```

It just passes a blank, as the variable has no value until the previous step. It's as though it is not inputting the variable prior to the package validation, so validation errors as it can't run the where clause of the query.

Banging my head against the wall with this, any help appreciated. Fully aware of injection issues surrounding this but it's purely for me to create SSIS data flow packages utilising a single sql table only I will have access to for variables. It'll speed up the onerous task a lot.

Comment: Unless every table in Oracle has the exact same shape (column names, data types) this isn't going to work

Comment: Hey, thanks @billinkc My table has some manual work, for example I add in the column names into a column, the PK column name into another.
It does work, I've ran it against a table where I just pull the whole table rather than using variables to grab the delta only.

Comment: But have you gone through a loop where you've switched from Customers to Sales? The data flow creates column bindings during design-time and at run-time it validates the source metadata matches expectation. Loop 1, we match because that's what we designed against. Loop 2, *boom* VS_NEEDS_NEWMETADATA

Comment: Oh, it doesn't automate at that level. I just want each step of the package to populate based on a sql table I've built, rather than going through various control and data flow tasks and changing "Table1" to "Table2".

I want to go into SSIS, copy my template package, change three variables manually "SourceSystem, SourceSchema, SourceTable" - which check against my SQL table for the associated DeltaColumn that i've also manually added to said table, and then the package will populate.

I'm not looking to fully automate the process, just the population of the different control tasks.

Comment: Examples of other components:

truncate table
 Input."+@[User::SourceTable]+"

update
 System.ETLLog
set
 LastExtractUTCDateTime = ?
, LastExtractDateTime = ?
, ExtractRowCount  = ?
where
 SourceSystem = '"+@[User::SourceSystem]+"'
and SourceSchema = '"+@[User::SourceSchema]+"'
and SourceTable = '"+@[User::SourceTable]+"'

Comment: Sounds like you're a perfect candidate for [Biml](https://billfellows.blogspot.com/2015/01/biml-replicate-o-matic.html) You have your metadata, you have standard pattern you'd like to implement and you're about to start stamping out a great quantity of packages. In my experience, somewhere about through this process you'll discover a teeny-tiny step you needed and then you have to recreate the first N packages or you end up with V1 and V2 patterns implemented in a single solution.